# The best structure of relationships and interactions between classes in task with two lines of development of the system

Tags: oop, design-patterns

What is the best structure of relationships and interactions between classes in task with two line of development of the system, where the implementation of one part depends on the second?

For example, I have several types of `Tree`'s. Each `Tree` gives a fixed number of fruits (this number is different for each tree). There is also a `Fertilizer` that increases the number of fruits on the tree by a fixed number of `m`. Moreover, `m` depends on the type of `Tree`. `Tree`'s and `Fertilizer`'s can be combined as desired.

The challenge is to find out the number of fruits in each `Tree`. At the same time, I would like to make a minimum of changes when adding new `Tree`'s and `Fertilizer`'s.

Is there a way to solve this problem elegantly using OOP (perhaps design patterns)?

Answer (score 0):

If every pairing between a `Tree` and a `Fertilizer` has a unique effect then there is really no way to design this nicely.  We want each piece of the puzzle to act independently without knowing what the whole puzzle looks like.  Say an `AppleTree` likes `Manure` but hates `BoneMeal`, we need to know that and store that somewhere, but this means that the `Tree` needs to know about all the available `Fertilizer` types.

In the real word a `Fertilizer` is defined by three numbers - `nitrogen`, `phosphate` and `potash`.  So I think it's safe to assume that a `Tree` can respond to the *properties* of a `Fertilizer` in some mathematical way.

Of course you can over-fertilize a `Tree` and kill it, so we probably want adding fertilizer to be an action that can be repeated, where the effects depend on the results of previous fertilizations.  So a `Tree` should keep a "state" with its current soil conditions.

I've taken your example very literally but I hope this helps.

```
interface NPK {
    nitrogen: number;
    phosphate: number;
    potash: number;
}

interface Fertilizer extends NPK {
    // what would be unique from one fertilizer to another?
    // I don't know
}

abstract class Tree {
    // has some other properties that maybe matter
    age: number;
    height: number;
    // keeps track of the minerals in its soil
    soil: NPK;

    constructor(initialSoil: NPK) {
        this.age = 0;
        this.height = 0;
        this.soil = initialSoil;
    }

    public fertilize( fertilizer: Fertilizer, quantity: number ) {
        // should really have some dampening, but you get the idea
        this.soil.nitrogen += fertilizer.nitrogen * quantity;
        this.soil.phosphate += fertilizer.phosphate * quantity;
        this.soil.potash += fertilizer.potash * quantity;
    }

    // each species will have its own method for calculating the
    // fruit quantity based on the other conditions
    abstract fruitQuantity(): number;
}

class AppleTree extends Tree {
    // concretions define their own algorithm for calculating quantity
    fruitQuantity(): number {
        // some math here based around an ideal number for each
    }
}
```